# Polynomial gcd of $x^5+x+1$ and $x^2+1$

Tags: polynomials, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

In a multiple choice assignment I had to find the gcd of

$$x^5+x+1$$

and

$$x^2+1$$

I can find it with the Euclidean algorithm, but that is taking me quite some time and work. Since this test was supposted to be solved very quickly there must be an easier method I guess. One of the multichoice answers was actually $1$ which is the correct solution. So I though maybe it's obvious that there is no gcd other than $1$ for this question? Is that so and if yes, why?

Comment: As $x^3(x^2+1) = x^5+x^3$, it is the same GCD as that of $-x^3 + x + 1$ and $x^2+1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $d(x)$ be the greatest common divisor, so that $d(x)\mid x^2+1$ and $d(x)\mid x^5+x+1$.

Suppose $d(x)\ne 1$.

Then any root of $d$ is a root of $x^2+1$, so equals $\pm i$.

Any root of $d$ is a root of $x^5+x+1$. But $(\pm i)^5 +(\pm i)+1=\pm 2i+1\ne 1$.

Hence $d(x)=1$.

[All this can be done in your head in seconds].

Comment: In $F_5[X]$, the PGCD is $X-2$. It can be also found in seconds because if $x^2=-1$ then $x^5 = x$, so if $x^5 + x + 1=0$ then $2x = -1$ hence $4 x^2 = 1$ hence $-4=1$ or $5=0$.

Answer (score 2):

One other way I see is to factorize $x^5+x+1$ over $\Bbb Q$. Since it has no rational root by the rational root theorem, we may assume that it is a product of a quadratic and a cubic polynomial. This quickly leads to
$$
x^5+x+1=(x^3 - x^2 + 1)(x^2 + x + 1),
$$
which is interesting in itself, and also implies that $\gcd(x^2+1,x^5+x+1)=1$.

Comment: Let : x = 2 $$ x^5+x+1=35 \\ 1+x^2=5 \\ So : gcd(x^5+x+1,1+x^2) = 5 \; not \;1 $$

Comment: @Mostafa A gcd is for polynomials, so for **all** $x$, not just $x=2$. So for example $gcd(x^2-1,x-1)=x-1$, for all $x$ then as a polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

Go to complex numbers, as the GCD is the same over real numbers and over complex numbers. (Euclid's algorithm doesn't "care" if you are executing it in $\mathbb R$ or in a bigger field.)

So, $x^2+1$ factorises as $(x-i)(x+i)$. Try the roots $i, -i$ in $x^5+x+1$ and you will get $2i+1$ and $-2i+1$, respectively. So none of the "prime" factors of $x^2+1$ divide $x^5+x+1$.

Thus, $x^2+1$ and $x^5+x+1$ are coprime and their gcd is $1$.

Comment: I read the other answers only after answering myself - only to realise that the highest-voted answer had exactly the same idea. I will still leave this answer here in case it is helpful to the OP.

Comment: It actually was very helpful to me, thank you!